# Can a private operator be accessible from outside?

Tags: c++, class, private

i.e. if I define operators == and + in my class in a private section, can they be accessible from main?

It works in MSVS 2008 and 2010 but for me it seems to be a bug in a compiler. Is it so?

Comment: When I was starting to program C++, I came to my mentor a couple of times saying: *look, there's a bug in the compiler! my code is not compiling/behaving as it should*. He used to smile back and answer: *Chances are that the bug lays between the chair and the keyboard*. Compilers have bugs, but more often than not it is our code or our understanding of that code that is wrong. You should post the actual code.

Comment: @David: Funny, the "suggestion" I got comes from SE and is "How do you tell if advice from a senior developer is bad?" ... Ah!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to show the code to get a sensible explanation of why the compiler is accepting it. My guess is that you are implementing them as `friend` free functions. At any rate, for the sake of argument, assume you have:

```
class bar {
   friend bool operator==( bar const &, bar const & ) {
      return true;
   }
   bar operator+( bar const & ) {
      return *this;
   }
};

int main() {
   bar a, b;
   a == b;    // ok
   //a + b;   // nok: operator+ is private from this context
}
```

And now the explanation. In the example, `operator+` is declared as a member function inside a private section, as such, access specifiers apply and unless `main` is a friend of the class it will not have access to it. On the other hand `operator==` is implemented as a free function (even if the definition is provided inside the class braces) and access specifiers do not apply there.

The code is almost equivalent (there is a small difference when it comes to lookup) to:

```
class bar {
   friend bool operator==( bar const &, bar const & ); // just declare as friend
   //...
};
bool operator==( bar const &, bar const & ) {
   return true;
}
```

Where it is much simpler to reason about accessibility of `operator==` from the main function.

Comment: Yes, I haven't noticed a friend declaration :(

Answer (score 5):

Functions or members declared under private access specifier will not be accessible outside the class member functions.

There are 3 access specifiers for a class/struct/Union in C++. These access specifiers define how the members of the class can be accessed. Of course, any member of a class is accessible within that class(Inside any member function of that same class). Moving ahead to type of access specifiers, they are:

***Public*** - The members declared as Public are accessible from outside the Class through an object of the class.
***Protected*** - The members declared as Protected are accessible from outside the class BUT only in a class derived from it.
***Private*** - These members are only accessible from within the class. No outside Access is allowed.

***Friends to the rescue!***
Declaring a function as ***friend*** inside another class allows that function to access all the member functions inside the class irrespective of the access specifier rules. ***friend*** It is a way to bypass the access specifier rules laid out in C++. Similary, a class declared as friend inside another class will allow the class being declared as friend to have access to all the members of the class. Note that the friend declaration can be given under any access specifer and it will have the same effect.

An source code example:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            int a;
        protected:
            int b;
        private:
            int c;
            friend void doSomething(MyClass obj);
    };

    void doSomething(MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.a = 10;     //Allowed
        obj.b = 20;     //Allowed, 
        obj.c = 30;     //Allowed, 
    }


    int main()
    {
        MyClass obj;
        obj.a = 10;     //Allowed
        obj.b = 20;     //Not Allowed, gives compiler error
        obj.c = 30;     //Not Allowed, gives compiler error
    }
```

***So in your usage if you are using `friend` then you can have access to the private members of the class or else your compiler is buggy you should consider changing it!***

Comment: VS2008 and VS2010 both being buggy in such a common piece of code, I don't think so. This is not a hidden corner case that might have escaped detection for the whole lifetime of VS2008 :)

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is : No. If its accessible from outside then what is the point of  being it `private`?

However, there is a twist.

If you make `main()` friend of the class, then its accessible **only** from `main()`. So the second answer is : it actually depends: Only member functions and friends can access the `private` member of a class.

```
class A
{
  int data; //private 
  friend int main();  //make main() friend of A
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.data = 100; //okay - main() is a friend of class A
}
void f()
{
    A a;
    a.data = 100; //error - f() is not a friend of class A
}
```

That means, I infer that `operator==` and `operator+` must be friends of the class in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a bug. They are accessible only by friend functions and friend classes. All other shouldn't have access to private section.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't added a friend declaration for main (don't know if that is even possible), the answer is no, so you apparently have found a compiler bug.